# Understanding reinforcement learning on game 2048 example

Tags: reinforcement-learning

So i wanna learn reinforcement learning by doing some examples. I wrote 2048 game but i do not know if i'm training it right. So as I understand I have to create neural network. I have created 16 inputs for each number. Then hidden layers 12x8 and 4 outputs for moves(up, right, down, left). (Activation function linear function for lat layer and relu for rest) Then I run one full game and save all the moves and rewards(0-nothing happend, -2-to moves that do nothink, -1 when that move lost game and a number of earned score when move do somethink). When the game ends I did backpropagation algorithm from the last move. Am i doing it rigth or what? And I know there are libraries like tensorflow but I wanna understand it all.

Comment: Have you looked at some learning resources first? Ex. 
Andrei Karpathy Blog: http://karpathy.github.io/2016/05/31/rl/ or 
https://medium.freecodecamp.org/an-introduction-to-reinforcement-learning-4339519de419

Answer (score 0):

I would consult [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/tjwei/2048-NN), as it accomplishes exactly what you are trying to do.

You can actually use the above solution live [here](https://tjwei.github.io/2048-NN/).

If you want to actually learn the fundamentals of how that all works, that's beyond the scope of what a single post on StackOverflow can provide.